# how to make a protobuf dependent lib avalaible in a non-protobuf environment?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a **C++** project depending on protobuf, but there's no guarantee that all users have protobuf installed on there own PC(**protobuf is only not the only way of serialization**) but they also want to use the project as a lib. In that case, dynamic linking to protobuf while compiling the project is not a choice(the project.so will dynamically depending on libprotobuf.so) what can I do?

Comment: I am currently scouting SO because I have exactly the same issue. My guess is that you want to somehow merge the protobuf static library into your own, but I'm not sure how to do that.